# Why does the type change in this simple map?

Tags: typescript

Why does this uneventful map change the type of the array?

I am doing a more complicated map than this but the goal is to keep the type the same through the map.

```
  const x: type1[] | type2[]=[]; // x has type type1[] | type2[]
  const y = x.map(item=>item);   // y has type (type1 | type2)[]
```

I am using typescript 4.3.5.

Comment: Wow, it changed the type from `type1` to `Test1`! 

Comment: @jcalz haha whoops, fixed that. Thanks david-arias for submitting the edit.

Comment: I have to go so I can't write an answer now, but `x.map()` is a union of methods, whose parameter is therefore an intersection of callback types (contravariance stuff), whose parameter is therefore a union of value types: `type1 | type2`.  The compiler does not say "oh `x.map(item=>item)` is whatever it would be if `x` were a `type1[]` unioned with whatever it would be if `x` were a `type2[]`."  It says "oh `x.map(item => item)` is some method call and `item` will be `type1` or `type2`.  And therefore it returns `type1 | type2`. This is correct, but loses information you care about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the signature of `Array<T>#map`:

```
map<U>(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U, thisArg?: any): U[];
```

`T` here is inferred to be `type1 | type2`, and `U` is inferred to be the same as `T`. Then the method returns `U[]` which is `(type1 | type2)[]`.

Comment: Ah, this makes more sense when looking at the signature. do you know of any way to "fix" (get past) this "problem" (intended behavior)?

Comment: @Daniel you can always throw around `// @ts-ignore` or `as any` but it's hard to suggest a solution without knowing the actual problem (surely you don't want to do a map with no actual function...) What you want to do is not necessarily safe (afaik) unless the map function returns `type1 & type2` which is not particularly practical